# Performing a batch check on PNG/TGA files to see if they use transparency?

Tags: bash, powershell, batch, images, png

The problem I'm facing is: I need to run a check against a huge pack of many files, including *.png and *.tga ones. I need to find out if they actually use the transparency/translucency/whatever can it be called anywhere.

I know how to check if the specific file has an ABILITY to use transparency. That's not what I'm looking for. I know you can, for instance, check byte 26 in PNG to see if it **supports** transparency. I need to find which files in the huge folder actually **use** it (have transparent parts, semi-transparent parts).

I can run PowerShell scrypts for that, Python scripts, or use Bash for Windows.

Would be grateful for help

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are a community of people interested in computers, not a free coding service. If you already have something written, we might be able to help you if you share it with us.

Comment: https://imagemagick.org/index.php and other command line tools have image property examination and are scriptable. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=check+image+transparency+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: With **ImageMagick** `magick *.png -format '%f: %[opaque]\n' info:`